# Cassandra .csv import error:batch too large

Tags: csv, import, cassandra, copy

I'm trying to import data from a .csv file to Cassandra 3.2.1 via copy command.In the file are only 299 rows with 14 columns. I get the Error:

**Failed to import 299 rows: InvalidRequest - code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Batch too large"**

I used the following copy comand and tryied to increase the batch size:

`copy table (Col1,Col2,...)from 'file.csv'
with delimiter =';' and header = true and MAXBATCHSIZE = 5000;`

I think 299 rows are not too much to import to cassandra or i am wrong?

Comment: Tried to increase the rows in the .csv step by step. 200 rows works fine, 300 not.

Answer (score 12):

Adding the CHUNKSIZE keyword resolved the problem for me.

e.g.
copy event_stats_user from '/home/kiren/dumps/event_stats_user.csv ' with CHUNKSIZE=1 ;

Comment: +1 this solved my problem without altering the cassandra.yaml/scylla.yaml. Im using ScyllaDB by the way.

Comment: This Solved the problem +!

Answer (score 8):

The error you're encountering is a server-side error message, saying that the **size** (in term of bytes count) of your batch insert is too large.

This batch size is defined in the `cassandra.yaml` file:

```
# Log WARN on any batch size exceeding this value. 5kb per batch by default.
# Caution should be taken on increasing the size of this threshold as it can lead to node instability.
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5

# Fail any batch exceeding this value. 50kb (10x warn threshold) by default.
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
```

If you insert a lot of big columns (in size) you may reach quickly this threshold. Try to reduce `MAXBATCHSIZE` to 200.

More info on COPY options **[here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy)**